# How to prove $|n-m|\lt d\implies |f(n)-f(m)|\lt e$ for the following condition?

Tags: functions, proof-verification, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to prove $\exists n\in\Bbb{N},\forall e\in \Bbb{R^+},\exists d\in\Bbb{R^+},\forall m\in\Bbb{N}, |n-m|\lt d\implies |f(n)-f(m)|\lt e$ if $f(x)=\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\rfloor$.

I don't know how to begin this question as I have a hard time finding relationship between $e$ and $d$.

Could someone help?

Comment: There isn't any relation between e and d.  All that there has to happen is that for every e you can find a d for that e that fulfils that requirement.